# How can I scrape data from a function which includes loops

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm learning Web Scraping (with Python and Beautiful Soup) and I encountered with a problem on how to scrape data within a function which contains loops. The data I'm trying to get is within the condition of if,else statement as shown below.(Page Source below)

I want to scrap "***Password :  h7s6sh***"

```
**<SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
var testV = 1;
var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
while (testV < 3) {
if (!pass1) 
history.go(-1);
if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "ratedr") 
{
  alert('You Got it Right!');
  document.write("<center><h1>Username : hellomrxyz@gmail.com<p>Password :  h7s6sh</p></h1><p>NOTE : Visit daily Everyday</p><p><h1>Thank You!</h1></p></center>");break;
   } 
 testV+=1;
 var pass1 = prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
}
if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) 
history.go(-1);
return " ";
} 
</SCRIPT>**
```

---

This is the script I'm trying on

**>>> script_mim.text**

```
u'\nfunction passWord() {\nvar testV = 1;\nvar pass1 = prompt(\'Please Enter Your Password\',\' \');\nwhile (testV < 3) {\nif (!pass1) \nhistory.go(-1);\nif (pass1.toLowerCase() == "ratedr") {\nalert(\'You Got it Right!\');\ndocument.write("<center><h1>Username : hellomrxyz@gmail.com<p>Password : h7s6sh</p></h1><p>NOTE : Visit daily Everyday</p><p><h1>Thank You!</h1></p></center>");\nbreak;\n} \ntestV+=1;\nvar pass1 = \nprompt(\'Access Denied - Password enter code hereIncorrect, Please Try Again.\',\'Password\');\n}\nif (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3) \nhistory.go(-1);\nreturn " ";\n} \n\n'
```

**>>> script_mim.find_all('p')**

[]

Why isn't anything being displayed? I'm using the latest version of python 3.x. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong, with a solution.

Comment: To understand the problem better it would help if you cleaned up the formatting a bit (particularly the `...text` down below) and give some more detail - What's your given scenario, your goal and the exact problem? What's the set-up of your context, what languages are you using for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful soup will only understand and try to parse the **tags** not data inside those tags. Since the extracted content of `<script>` tag will be a unicode string you can't parse the result. So, You have to do string operations on the result in order to get the output. Either you can find the index of `<p>` and `</p>` and can extract that tag using list comprehension and reparse it using beautiful soup to get output **(method 1)** or You can do direct string operation on the result in order to get the output **(method 2)**.

1. If you go by reparsing the `<p></p>` tag extracted by string
   operation using BeautifulSoup then your code will be

   ```
   soup=BeautifulSoup(script_mim.text[272:script_mim.text.find('</h1>')],"html.parser") #reinitialize beautifulsoup by extarcting <p> tag
   soup.find("p").get_text() #this will give you desired output.
   ```
2. If you go by string operations to parse data and get password then
   your code will be

   ```
   script_mim.text[script_mim.text.find('<p>')+3:script_mim.text.find('</h1>')]
   ```

I would recommend method 2 since string operation is inexpensive when compared to method 1.